# How to set up MySQLi connection to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysqli, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I need to use MySQL to send queries to a Google Cloud SQL database set up.  I already have an instance created and a user, and I am able to access the database through the Cloud Shell.  I can't seem to find the credentials to log into the database (host name, username, password, port and socket), and I'm not sure how to access them through the shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the available methods to connect to your Cloud SQL instance [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/external-connection-methods).

Connecting from an IP address without SSL is probably the easiest one:

- In the Cloud Console, go to the [cloud SQL instances screen](https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances) and click on your instance’s name.
- In the overview tab, take note of the Primary IP Address, you’ll use it instead of a hostname.
- In the users tab, you can create a new user or reset the password of an existente one, including the root user.
- In the authorization tab, add the ip or ip range where you are attempting the connection from, so Cloud SQL accept connections from your client (more on this [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip#add)).
- Start your mysql client as follows (note the port is not necessary as the default one is used):

mysql --host=[INSTANCE_IP_ADDR] --user=[USER_NAME] --password